# Internet seems ridiculously slow

Tags: wireless, networking

At this current time.. it's letting me post. I think I may have posted before on this issue,  but I can't find the topic anymore.

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on here, and it was working to start. Now when I boot up my laptop it won't load webpages (sometimes it MIGHT if I wait like 10 minutes.)

It's going fast currently, but still when I boot I  have to disconnect the wifi and then connect again for it to work. I haven't tried Windows on here.. but the other 2 laptops with Windows 7 work just fine. Earlier today though, it was just god awful slow no matter how many times I disconnected my modem, rebooted, and disabled/re-enabled wifi on here.

I did try booting up a live Fedora CD to see if I had the same problem, but I did not.

Details: Laptop is a Toshiba Satellite C75D-A

Running the command #[sudo lshw -C network] gets me this information, let me know if you need me to run anything else.

## [description: Wireless interface

```
   product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 64:5a:04:c0:13:1f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=3.11.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

]

Thank you for taking your time to read this and for any help. :)

Comment: Driver parameters for an ath9k or iwlagn, which no longer exists, will not help your rtl8188ee driver. Disabling IPv6 might help. It can easily be done in Network Manager.

Comment: Thank you, but I already disabled that with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I suggest a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also suggest a fixed channel, either 1 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add the line:

```
iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. If these changes do not help, please try compiling the driver backported from kernel version 3.13. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

I suggest you download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13.2/backports-3.13.2-1.tar.xz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13.2-1/
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

It may take a reboot. Your wireless should now be working better. You will have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after reboot, re-compile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13.2-1/
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Comment: I did those suggestions. It kinda of worked. I still have some slow wifi now and then. I ended up ordering http://www.amazon.com/Panda-Ultra-Wireless-Adapter-150Mbps/dp/B00762YNMG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1396555859&sr=8-1&keywords=panda+usb+wireless because I heard it was a better solution than the wireless card I have for Linux. Thank you.

Comment: When you get and install it, it will be helpful to blacklist rtl8188ee so there is no conflict. Post a new question if you nee guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the info. :) I'm running off ethernet till it gets here.